# batch get current directory without drive letter

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I get the current working directory and get the path without the drive letter for instance:

```
C:\testing\test\test
I would like to get in a variable
testing\test\test
```

How can I trim the drive letter?
I can get the full path using

```
set fullPath = %CD%
```

I can't use the %~d0 notation as it gives me the path of my script versus the actual working directory I'm in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the following link:

```
set fullPath=%cd:~3%
echo %fullPath%
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/28/362565.aspx

Comment: Very handy, this means I can dump a batch file in a folder and run it so the contents of that folder get mirrored exactly to another drive letter, without manually dragging stuff across copying it or constantly editing the batch file to reflect the current folder path, cheers. Example: `robocopy "%CD%" "S:\%fullPath%" /E /XJ /w:0 /r:0 /ndl /njh /njs | find /v "*EXTRA File"`

Answer (score 4):

```
%cd:~3%
```

eg:

```
C:\testing\test\test>echo %cd:~3%
testing\test\test

C:\testing\test\test>
```

DOS string manipulations,  here:

http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.MidString

Comment: This is great it seems to work from the command line but for some reason it does not work when I trigger this batch script through the context menu (right click and click on a new menu I added that executes this script) in that instance I get a blank fullPath, any idea?