# How to run a .cmd file from changing location [SD Card]

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am working on a gaming library that can be put onto an sd card and different Windows devices.  All of the files for the emulators and roms are within one folder.  When I move the sd card around, it will change from A Drive to D Drive, etc.

How would I write a cmd file that doesn't require the entire address of the file but rather just checks the shared parent folder and then routes from there.

On a command line you can do the two dots (..) but I'm not sure how to do this on a written file.  Here is my file and it's location explained below.

**File Location:**
A:\Console\Nintendo\64\cmdfiles\SuperMario64.cmd

**Code:**

```
@echo off
echo Starting Super Mario 64...
call "Nintendo64.cmd" "A:\Console\Nintendo\64\Games\Super Mario 64.n64"
```

**Desired Code:**

```
@echo off
echo Starting Super Mario 64...
call "Nintendo64.cmd" "..\Games\Super Mario 64.n64"
```

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903020/batch-get-current-directory-without-drive-letter

Comment: you mean like `"%~dp0..\Games\Super Mario 64.n64"` where `%~dp0` is the drive/path of the batchfile itself..

Comment: @Christian, `cd` is not reliable for this, if run as admin, your working directory by default is `%windir%\system32`. Also, any `cd` or `pushd` command will end up in a different `c`urrent `d`irectory (`cd`).